# Objective-C: incompatible pointer type error

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I am struggling with Objective-C... can't seem to get the differences between it and C#... anyway, I have the following code, which is giving me a build error

```
NSString* databasePath = @"some string";

if (sqlite3_open(databasePath, &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
}
```

On the `sqlite3_open` line, I get the following compiler error:

> Passing Argument 1 of 'sqlite_open' from incompatible pointer type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the linker error (you need to add libsqlite3.dylib to your project as per the answer provided by @JeremyP) in this instance, the `sqlite3_open` command is expecting a constant character pointer, which you could create from the NSString you have as follows:

```
    // Get the path to the database file
    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ppcipher.s3db"];

    // Open the database file
    const char *cDatabasePath = [databasePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    sqlite3_open(cDatabasePath, &database);
```

If you look at the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html), you can generally see what's expected. For example:

```
int sqlite3_open(
  const char *filename,   /* Database filename (UTF-8) */
  sqlite3 **ppDb          /* OUT: SQLite db handle */
);
```

Comment: Actully, there was a slight typo in the first line of my answer.  It's libsqlite3.dylib

Comment: @JeremyP Thanks for the heads up. I've updated my answer accordingly. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's trying to tell you that you are not linking libsqlite3.dylib into your application.  What you need to do is:

- select the target for your application
- right click it and select "get info"
- in the "linked libraries" pane of the first tab, find the MacOS X librarly libsqlite3.dylib and add it to your project.

Oh yes, and as others have said, you need to pass a C string to the function call, not an NSString.  The easiest way is by using the `-UTF8String` method of `NSString`.

Comment: +1 Missed that bit and skipped straight to the warning. Bad me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

sqlite is a C library, not an Objective-C library.  It doesn't know about NSString* (the 1st argument).  It's expecting char* (or something like that).

Use:

```
[databasePath UTF8String]
```

as the argument to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this in place of the SQLite API. It's a wrapper named FMDB that makes things MUCH easier: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Answer (score 0):

This is the linker stage where all symbols generated in the compilation stage are resolved.  In your case the sqlite_open function cannot be found.  Have you included all appropriate libraries and frameworks?

Comment: Josh:  Can't use FMDB 'cause I'm "trying" to use SQLCipher.  

JeremyP:  There was NOTHING in the instructions for "wiring" it to the app that said anything about .dylib

Lou Franco:  made the change as you suggested... now I get this (see: http://imgur.com/M04rQ)